# I have a formula for only 1 light but I need to get 2 lights

Tags: opengl, glsl, formula, fragment-shader, lighting

I'm making an engine from scratch (not out of my own free will ofc) and I need to make it where my object has at least 2 separate light sources. I'm using vertex.shader and fragment.shader for this formula. Sadly this formula only can show one light but as stated I need to get the formula to show at least 2.

This is the Vertex.shader:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 vPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec4 vNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 vTexCoord;
layout(location = 3) in vec4 vTangent;
layout(location = 4) in vec4 vColor;

uniform mat4 projectionViewMatrix;
uniform mat4 modelMatrix;

out vec4 fPosition;
out vec4 fNormal;
out vec4 fColor;

void main() {
 fPosition = vPosition;
 fNormal = modelMatrix * vNormal;
 fColor = vColor;
 gl_Position = projectionViewMatrix * modelMatrix * vPosition;
}
```

Fragment.shader:

```
#version 410

in vec4 fPosition;
in vec4 fNormal;
in vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 kAmbient;
uniform vec3 kDiffuse;
uniform vec3 kSpecular;
uniform float kSpecularPower;

uniform vec3 iDirection;
uniform vec3 iAmbient;
uniform vec3 iDiffuse;
uniform vec3 iSpecular;

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

out vec4 pColor;

void main() {
  vec3 kNormal = normalize(fNormal.xyz);
  vec3 iNormal = normalize(iDirection);

  //Calculate ambient color
  vec3 ambientColor = (fColor.xyz + kAmbient) * iAmbient;

  //Calculate diffuse color
  float lambertTerm = dot(kNormal, -iNormal);
  lambertTerm = max(0.0f, min(1.0f, lambertTerm));
  vec3 diffuseColor = (fColor.xyz + kDiffuse) * iDiffuse * lambertTerm;

  //Calculate specular color
  vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(cameraPosition - fPosition.xyz);
  vec3 reflectionNormal = reflect(iNormal, kNormal);
  float specularTerm = dot(surfaceToView, reflectionNormal);
  specularTerm = max(0.0f, specularTerm);
  specularTerm = pow(specularTerm, kSpecularPower);
  vec3 specularColor = (fColor.xyz + kSpecular) * iSpecular * specularTerm;

  pColor = vec4(ambientColor + diffuseColor + specularColor, 1.0f);
}
```

I've thought that maybe I should try to create a new position but that doesn't seem to work. It either doesn't load or is a solid color.

this is what I have so far so you can get what I'm going with this:
[Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpDoT.png)

Comment: Don't post code as images, paste it into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that your `k*` uniforms are material properties and `i*` uniforms are light properties. This seems to be inspired by the legacy OpenGL light model -- which was a total mess and made no sense:

- `kAmbient/iAmbient` is a global scene property, not a material or light property.
- `kDiffuse` isn't really needed when your color comes from the vertex shader (i.e. `fColor`).
- `iSpecular` isn't needed either -- the color of specular highlights is determined by material specular tint and the color of the light, thus `kSpecular*iDiffuse`.

Putting the rest into uniform blocks we get:

```
struct Light {
    vec3 iDirection;
    vec3 iColor;
};

uniform Lights {
    vec3 iAmbient;
    int nlights;
    Light lights[MAX_LIGHTS];
};

uniform Material {
    //vec3 kDiffuse; // optional
    vec3 kSpecular;
    float kSpecularPower;
};
```

What's left is to iterate over all the lights and accumulate their contribution:

```
void main() {
    vec3 kNormal = normalize(fNormal.xyz);
    vec3 surfaceToView = normalize(cameraPosition - fPosition.xyz);

    vec3 diffuse = iAmbient;
    vec3 specular = vec3(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < nlights; ++i) {
        Light light = lights[i];
        vec3 iNormal = normalize(light.iDirection);
        float lambertTerm = max(0.0f, -dot(kNormal, iNormal));
        diffuse += light.iColor * lambertTerm;
        
        vec3 reflectionNormal = reflect(iNormal, kNormal);
        float specularTerm = max(0.0f, dot(surfaceToView, reflectionNormal));
        specularTerm = pow(specularTerm, kSpecularPower);
        specular += light.iColor * specularTerm;
    }
    
    pColor = vec4(fColor.xyz*diffuse + kSpecular*specular, 1.0f);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this didn't work, it especially didn't like it when I did light.iColor and such

Comment: @CaiChi: what do you mean by "didn't like it"?